# Is DNSSEC useful?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, dnssec

DNSSEC validate and authenticate zone data with the purposeto make sure that whatever DNS results, those are genuine.

1. Even if a DNS resolver validates that an authoritative nameserver has send the right data untampered, how do we prevent the DNS resolver from sending tampered DNS response to the DNS client?
2. If the DNS resolver does not support DNSSEC, can it still send DNS queries to an authoritative nameserver that has DNSSEC enabled for its zone?

Thank you

Comment: 1. is fairly easy. Validation and enforcement must be done on the client. Period. Windows can do this natively, I'm not sure about Linux or other platforms.

Comment: @GregAskew Just install unbound and it can validate everything locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is DNSSEC useful?

This can't be answered (for whatever word you put instead of "DNSSEC" in that sentence) until you start describing against what you want to defend.

When you have the list of risks/vulnerabilities/threats against which you want to defend yourself then you can find out which solutions exist and determine for each solution how much it is useful or not.

`DNSSEC` is useful against some sort of DNS problems but not on all of them. It introduces itself new problems (ongoing maintenance of signatures and keys for one) but also new features (aggressive caching of everything below a `NXDOMAIN` if properly validated by DNSSEC).

> Even if a DNS resolver validates that an authoritative nameserver has send the right data untampered - how do we prevent the DNS resolver from sending tampered DNS response to the DNS client ?

This is nothing different from today: if you use any public DNS resolver (`8.8.8.8`, `1.1.1.1`, `9.9.9.9` to name a few), you are of course COMPLETELY at the risk of it sending you garbage data. That is a tradeoff. DoH/DoT does not solve anything here because it will protect only the content transmission between you and this resolver, not the content itself. Which content is "protected" by DNSSEC as long as the domain name for which you are doing queries is DNSSEC protected (which is one part you forget in your questions and which make in fact DNSSEC difficult: domain name owner have to enable it **AND** DNS resolvers have to use the new signatures and do the validation; if one part of this 2 variables equation is not there, DNSSEC is not useful because it just can't work)

So the question revolves more around: which recursive nameserver to use, and where should it run. Of course, for maximum control, you want the resolver to run on YOUR machines. It can still use external resources and DNS resolvers there, but the final DNSSEC validation should happen on your nameserver, not others. Of course this is more work than just relying on any other resource that do all the DNSSEC stuff "for free" for you.

> if the DNS resolver does not support DNSSEC, can it still send DNS queries to an authoritative nameserver that has DNSSEC setup for its zone ?

Yes.
A resolver wanting to have DNSSEC data has to switch the "DO" flag in its request.

From `dig` documentation:

```
        +[no]dnssec
         This option requests that DNSSEC records be sent by setting the DNSSEC OK (DO) bit in the OPT record in the additional section of the query.
```

Which you can see that way:

```
$ dig +dnssec example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.18 <<>> +dnssec example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40492
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 4096
                           ^^
```

Or from §3.2.1 of RFC 4035:

> 3.2.1.  The DO Bit
>
> The resolver side of a security-aware recursive name server MUST set
> the DO bit when sending requests, regardless of the state of the DO
> bit in the initiating request received by the name server side.  If
> the DO bit in an initiating query is not set, the name server side
> MUST strip any authenticating DNSSEC RRs from the response but MUST
> NOT strip any DNSSEC RR types that the initiating query explicitly
> requested.

If the DNS client (recursive resolver) does this AND if the authoritative nameserver being queried has DNSSEC enabled (hence `RRSIG`/`NSEC`/`NSEC3` record types in the zones), then the resolver will get those records and then can do the DNSSEC validation.

When you (a DNS stub/client not being a resolver) query a recursive resolver, you have the option of using the `CD` flag, defined as such:

```
        +[no]cdflag
        This option sets [or does not set] the CD (checking disabled) bit in the query. This requests the server to not perform DNSSEC validation of responses.
```

(beware of the possible double negation).

If the client does not use `CD`, then DNSSEC validation is NOT disabled, hence it is enabled and the remove server will either serve the final answer (if DNSSEC is enabled for the record AND the validation was a success) or will reply with `NXDOMAIN` if the DNSSEC validation failed.
The flag `AD` will be set to denote that all records were validated as secure, if it is the case (if the query comes from a recursive nameserver, that flag can't exist from an authoritative one as you need the full DNSSEC chain from IANA root to validate any given record)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ideally you validate locally on the client (not all that common today but far from unheard of), or otherwise rely on a secure network path that can bridge the gap from the client to a trusted validating resolver.
   This secure network path could mean something like DNS-over-TLS, DNS-over-HTTPS, DNSCrypt or to some extent a local network (weaker level of trust, but still useful for a subset of attack scenarios).
2. Yes

Comment: For 1. I think DNSSEC implementations that don't validate on the client are dangerous. This is also platform-specific. There are more Windows remote endpoints, so that's where the risk is. Client validation on Windows is easy to configure and not doing so would be just wrong. It isn't an all or nothing scenario. From a Windows client perspective, most risk exposure is with internal domains, so if only those were enforced it would be a good start. On the server side, all key rotations are automated so it pretty much works, you just end up with a truckload more DNS records and bandwidth used.

Comment: @GregAskew Any pointers for how this is done on Windows?

Comment: Name Resolution Policy Table. You can require DNSSEC/IPSEC for domain name(s).  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn593632(v=ws.11)

Comment: @GregAskew Thank you for clarifying. However, I have seen those settings but to my understanding the "require validation" option there doesn't mean to do client validation but that the client requires `AD` flag to be set? That approach is problematic both in that it completely relies on that the traffic to the configured resolver is safe from tampering, but it's also impossible to enable that option globally as it will discard anything that is not signed as opposed to normal validation behavior of discarding things that are bogus (ie, should be signed but did not come with a valid signature)

Comment: @GregAskew The IPSec option on the other hand lands firmly in the "create a secure network path to a trusted resolver" approach that I suggested in my answer. IPSec certainly works for doing that, although it is quite specific to something you can set up with your own infrastructure rather than expect any other service provider to provide (which is fine, it just limits the scope where it is applicable). But all in all, none of the options seem to provide validation on the client, as far as I can tell?